# getting value of name attribute which has array value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

i am having a input file element capable of uploading multiple files.
i want to get the names of files using Jquery.
if my uploaded file names are gg.pdf,hj.pdf.i have to get it as an array.

```
jQuery( ".fileinput-button" ).click(function() {
   
var values = jQuery("input[name='files\\[\\]'")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
      console.log(values);        
});
   
});
```

i had tried this but i am not getting file names.This is my input element.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="filenames" multiple>
```

anybody pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the filenames via the name attribute of the input, you will need to use a FileReader instead. Try something like:

```
$("#filenames").change(function(event){
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
  for (const file of files) {
    console.log(file.name);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event of jquery and then store the file name in `array` using `push` method . And on click of button show uploaded file.

**Demo Code** :

```js
var files_data = [];
//onchnge of file input
jQuery('#filenames').on('change', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    files_data.push(this.files[i].name);//push file name in array
  }
});
///on click of btn
jQuery(".fileinput-button").click(function() {
//array
  console.log(files_data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="filenames" multiple>

<button class="fileinput-button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get the file names in an array **filenames**

```
  var files = $("input[name='files\\[\\]'").files;
  let filenames =Object.keys(files).map(function(key, index) {
  return files[key].name 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

has the input field have an `ID` you can use It to target that element

```js
$('#filenames').on('change', (event) => {
    let values = Array.from(event.target.files).reduce((acc, file) =>  {
      acc.push(file.name);
      return acc
    }, []);
    
    console.log(values);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="filenames" type="file" name="file" multiple>
```

To access the list of files which are selected you can use the property `file` of the input field of type file. this is explain on the  documentation.

[image]

And the value which is return is of type [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) and It contain [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) so to get access to the name of each file I create an `Array` from that list of files. To get access `Array` method.

```
let = Array.from($('#filenames').files);
```

After that I can have access to every `Array` methods so I can call `map` `forEach` and whatever array method which can allow me to loop through the content of the `FileList`. I my case I prefere to use `reduce` as I just want to return the and **Array** of file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access to the value attribute of your file input on the change event.

**code:**

```
document.getElementById('filenames').onchange = function () {
  alert('Selected file: ' + this.value);
};
```